# Null pointer exception on testng

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I have written the below code and getting the java null pointer exception.
please help what is the problem.

```
public class testngbasics {

  WebDriver driver;

     @BeforeMethod
      public void setbrowser() {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe");
             WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
             driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
             driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/v4/");
             driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
             driver.manage().window().maximize();
             driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

     }

     @Test
      public void login1() {

         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='uid']")).sendKeys("mngr212595");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys("EgebYpy");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='LOGIN']")).click();
         System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
     }

     @AfterMethod

     public void closebrowser()
     {

         driver.close();
     }
}
```

I am getting the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException it is only going to @beforemethod
>   annotation and not going to @test and @aftermethod

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

As you have already defined a global instance of *WebDriver* as `driver` in the line:

```
WebDriver driver;
```

You don't have to create another instance of *WebDriver* again as in:

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
```

And you need to replace this line as:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```